# What makes difference in computing time between (insertion sort using 'while') and (insertion sort using 'for')?

Tags: c++, c, sorting

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void insertion_sort_f(int *A, int s, int e) {
    int j, i, tmp;
    for (j = s+1; j < e; j++) {
        tmp = A[j];     
        for (i = j - 1; i >= 0 && A[i] > tmp; i--)
            A[i+1] = A[i];          
        A[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
}
void insertion_sort_w(int *A, int s, int e) {
    int j, i, tmp;
    for (j = s + 1; j < e; j++) {
        tmp = A[j];
        i = j;
        while (--i >= 0 && A[i] > tmp) {
            A[i + 1] = A[i];
        }
        A[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I test two insertion sort with 100000 data, one is using 'for' and other one is using 'while'.
I guess no meaningful difference in computing time.
but 'while' is faster than 'for' about 1000ms average.
which one makes this result?

ps.
I post full code for explain. https://colorscripter.com/s/56xWn0O

Comment: Are you testing with compiler optimizations enabled? I did some quick tests and there isn't a significant difference between both functions.

Comment: @ Blastfurnace Oh, you are right! I changed 'debug' to 'release', so there is no difference in computing time. Thanks~

Comment: but I still don't know what makes different in 'debug' mode.

Comment: In debug mode, the compiler doesn't try hard to optimize; it uses whatever machine code seems easiest that is a faithful representation of what you ask for.

Comment: Debug == "deliberately slowed down". In a debug build, every time you modify a variable, it will take the value from the register, and write it to a memory location. This is so that the debugger can simply look at a memory address to find out the variables current value.

Comment: With `-O2`, `gcc` produces identical code for both (and there's no pointe in comparing the unoptimized version)

Comment: I debug mode, the compiler doesn't go out of its way to optimise (e.g. removing unnecessary operations, reordering for performance).   If you write down the sequence of operations expressed by your code exactly, you will see the two code samples do things differently - even if they have the same net effect for the caller of your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the function to:

```cpp
void insertion_sort_w(int *A, int s, int e) {
    int j, i, tmp;
    for (j = s + 1; j < e; j++) {
        tmp = A[j];
        i = j - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && A[i] > tmp) {
            A[i + 1] = A[i];
            --i;
        }
        A[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

clang and gcc will produce identical output for both methods. https://godbolt.org/z/8Hzxys

With your original implementation, the difference between the ASM produced for both methods is minimal. I'd be truly astonished if *(with optimisations on!)* there was any significant performance difference between the two.

Looking a bit closer at the ASM: https://godbolt.org/z/Xo3hZ7

Your while loop version does indeed produce less ASM, *however* that won't mean it's any faster. It just means that the compiler has generated some additional code blocks and jumps in the for loop version. This *might* actually make the for loop version marginally faster, since it may have an additional early out that the while loop version does not. Then again, the additional jumps may be an issue.

Using a profiler such as vtune is probably the best bet to get a clear idea of the relative performance.

Comment: I tried again 3 type insertion sort(my 2, your 1). my 'while' is faster than others. and your and my 'for' got same speed.

Comment: I don't believe you. Are you compiling with optimisations enabled, or are you building a debug build?

Comment: debug mode. I post my full code. I did default setting in visual studio.    http://colorscripter.com/s/56xWn0O

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of things that can affect the actual execution time of the code. IMHO, unless you're writing hardware-specific, real-time code, I wouldn't except much of a difference in performance.

1. Compiler optimization
   Breaking down a loop can be optimized by using [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling). It is possible that the compiler does this more efficiently for one of the loop types.
2. CPU optimization
   In pipelined CPUs, branching can harm performance. If you look at the generated assembly code for a 'for' or 'while' loop, you will have a conditional branching command (either execute another iteration or continue to code after the loop). Simply put, the CPU doesn't want to wait for the result of the conditional branch to execute the next command, so it "guesses" the next command, and later decides whether to discard the result or not (Read [Branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) and [Tomasulo algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm) ).
   Whether prediction is more efficient on one loop or the other, I honestly don't know, but this can theoretically make a difference.